# How to make a redirect so that a request with the necessary headers comes to the target address

Tags: spring, kotlin, redirect, oauth-2.0

I need to redirect the user so that the authorization token is in the header in the direct request after the redirect. But when I put a token in the redirect headers, it is not transferred to the target request.

```
@Component
class OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler() : SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

    override fun onAuthenticationSuccess(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        authentication: Authentication
    ) {
        val targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(request, response, authentication)

        if (response.isCommitted) {
            logger.debug("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to $targetUrl")
            return
        }

        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request)

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl)
    }

    override fun determineTargetUrl(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        authentication: Authentication
    ): String? {
        val token = "some.jwt.token"
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token)

        return "http://example.com/page_for_redirect" 
    }
}
```

I 'm doing this as part of Oauth2 . But I also didn't get it if I just create a method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ["/testredirect"], method = [RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET])
    fun testredirect(response: HttpServletResponse): ModelAndView? {
        response.setHeader("AUTHORIZATION","ABOBA")
        response.sendRedirect("http://example.com/page_for_redirect")
        return null
    }
```

As a result, I get a 302 response in which there is a necessary header and a Location header. Then there is a request to the address from Location, but without the necessary AUTHORIZATION header.

How do I make the headers shift between redirect and a direct request?